# Display images dynamically into list view items

Tags: android, database, listview, imageview, adapter

i develop android apps since one year so i'm not able to solve this kind of problem. I searched many times on our friend google but 0 real result. This is a very precise question, i try to display images dynamically into listview items, i mean :

1- I receive an array of int from my database (ex : 5, 6, 7, 7)

2- I want the adpater to display differents images depending of this numbers

for exemple i receive : "result" = {"1", "2", "3"} i want the app to associate images to this numbers (Images come from drawable folder)

> if (int number = 1) {
>   imageview into item layout.setImageRessource(R.id.blabla)
>   }else ...

I really don't know how do that, i tried building a custom adapter but it doesn't display the listview...

I'll be the happiest developper if somebody can tell me what the good way to do that.

```js
protected void showList() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON2);
        Poeple2 = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < Poeple2.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = Poeple2.getJSONObject(i);
            String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
            int mood = c.getInt(TAG_MOOD);

            HashMap<String, String> persons = new HashMap<String, String>();

            persons.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
            persons.put(TAG_MOOD, String.valueOf(mood));
            personList2.add(persons);
        }

        // i used a simple adapter but i know it's a wrong way
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), personList2, R.layout.modeluser4, new String[]{TAG_USERNAME, TAG_MOOD}, new int[]{R.id.tvHypo2, R.id.tvId});
        list3.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a switch like

```
public void runTheSwitch(int num){
int number = num;
switch(number){
 case 1:
     //add image to listview
 case 2:
     //add image to listview
 case 3:
     //add image to listview

    ....and so on...
  }
 }
```

When you recieve the Array of numbers from database (lets call it **ArrayNum**), run a loop through those num.

```
For(int num : ArrayNum){
  runTheSwitch(num);

}
```

Put this into a method and run the method before you set your adapter. 
So basically in this method you add items to your Arraylist like `arraylist.add();` 
then after this you define an Object of your custom adapter and pass the Arraylist in your adapter.
Hope it helps

Comment: do you put this into adapter class ? can u be a little bit more precise please ?

Comment: i fail from the begeining ... can we have a short skype call ?